# Data template at backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Tell me, please, how to create templates in Backbone.js, if there is a nested data.

Data example:

```
var questions = [
    {
        id: 0,
    question: [
        {
            id: 101,
            text: 'What is your name?',
        },
        {
            id: 102,
            text: 'What is your lastname?',
        },
        {
            id: 103,
            text: 'What is yout sex?',
        },
        {
            id: 104,
            text: 'How old are you?',
        },
    ]
}
];
```

And the html-code for output:

```
<div id="qu_0" class="questions"><div>
    <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_0" id="i101" value="101" /><label for="i101">What is your name?</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_0" id="i102" value="102" /><label for="i102">What is your firstname?</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_0" id="i103" value="103" /><label for="i103">What is your sex?</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_0" id="i104" value="104" /><label for="i104">How old are you?</label></p>
    <button type="button" name="next"><b>Answer</b></button>
</div></div>
```

I understand that I should get something like this:

```
<script id="questionTemplate" type="text/template">
<div>
    <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_<%= id %>" id="i<%= q.id %>" value="<%= q.id %>" /><label for="i<%= q.id %>"><%= q.text %></label></p>
    <button type="button" name="next"><b>Answer</b></button>
</div>
</script>
```

But I don't know how to display a nested array of questions in the template. Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through an array like this:

```
<script id="questionTemplate" type="text/template">
    <% for(var question in questions) { %>
        <div id="qu_<%= question.id %>" class="questions"><div>
        <% for(var q in questions,question) { %>
            <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_<%= q.id %>" id="i<%= q.id %>" value="<%= q.id %>" /><label for="i<%= q.id %>"><%= q.text %></label></p>
        <% } %>
        </div></div>
    <% } %>
    <button type="button" name="next"><b>Answer</b></button>
</script>
```

Comment: Read [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/722238)

Comment: Thanks! I resolved this problem with _.each():
`<script id="questionTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div>
     <% _.each(question, function(q) { %>
        <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_<%= id %>" id="i<%= q.id %>" value="<%= q.id %>" /><label for="i<%= q.id %>"><%= q.text %></label></p>
        <% }); %>
        <button type="button" name="next"><b>Answer</b></button>
    </div>
    </script>`

Comment: @fbynite: Use "for...in" is in no way "such a bad idea".  It simply has some quirks which good coders should be aware of.  In this case, none of those quirks apply.

Comment: Your wrong, good coders don't use `for .. in` to iterate an array without good reason. Besides, you have no idea whether FladeX has modified `Array.prototype` properties which will show up in the iteration.  Furthermore, when using `for .. in` the order is not specified. In this example, using `for .. in` is just plain wrong.

Comment: You're obviously not going to sleep well unless I say this so... fine, you're right and I'm wrong.  Happy?  Enjoy your black and white world.